# Jekyll blog do I have to make simliar htmls

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll, sidebar

I'm making a jekyll blog, and this is the link.
https://jinmc.github.io/programmingTips/

You can also look at the code from here : https://github.com/jinmc/programmingTips

Right now I just finished making the sidebars, 
and I know how it works, and implemented on just one keyword csharp.
Rest of it doesn't work.

I implemented this by making a csharp.html file and implementing this code on it.

```
---
layout: default
sidebar: sidebar_nav
---

<h1>C Sharp</h1>
<ul>
    {% for posts in site.categories.csharp %}
    <li>
    {%- assign date_format = site.minima.date_format | default: "%b %-d, %Y" -%}
            <span class="post-meta">{{ posts.date | date: date_format }}</span>
            <h3>
            <a class="post-link" href="{{ posts.url | relative_url }}">{{posts.title}}</a>
            </h3>
            <p>{{posts.meta}}</p>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

something like this.

I can make every html regarding the sidebar navigations but I'm starting to wonder
if this is good practice as the content inside it would be almost similar. Plus, I'll have to make every other html files every time I make a new category. But still, can't think of anything that could automate this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing a JavaScript method that listens for clicks on the navbar elements and selectively hiding or showing the relevant post links.

Modify `_layouts/home.html` so that it renders a `ul` containing all post links and a `ul` for each category that contains all the post links for that category. Add ids to these `ul` element that identify the category or 'all'. Use jQuery to hide all the category specific `ul` elements on page load. Use another `script` in the `_layouts/default.html` defining a global var initialized to 'all', a click listener that listens for which the different category clicks in the navbar and hides the previously shown `ul` and shows the desired `ul` by applying css styles. You can also change text on the page to show what the current category is.

Comment: Wow thanks, this is great! I should definitely try this, but where should I put this code in?

Comment: I changed my answer because Jekyll generates static html files and my original answer would have depended on the pages being generated upon request. I think the best solution is JavaScript.

Comment: I think this is way hard for me, I'll just make all the htmls.. as they work, but thanks anyway, I just think I'm not good at javascript enough to do this now.

Comment: Ok, I saw some `script` tags in the HTML so I thought you were conversant with JS. You shouldn't need anything more complex than what's currently written, but it is a struggle at first putting the pieces together. When you do reach that point, I think you'll realize that JS will create a better feel than skipping around page to page. GL